# PayPal REST API Create Invoice with Template

Tags: rest, api, paypal, invoice

Has anybody ever successfully created a PayPal invoice with a specific chosen template?
I can't seem to get it to work.

Have tried specifying the template_id in the call, and have also tried setting the desired template as the default.  In both cases, the API response contains the chosen template ID, but when the invoice is sent, it does not use the chosen template (can tell because there's no logo).

This the the API call:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices/ \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" \
-d '{
  "template_id": "TEMP-66B140465N059453G",
  "items": [
  {
    "name": "Part E",
    "quantity": 2,
    "unit_price": {
    "currency": "USD",
    "value": "10.15"
    }
  }
  ],
  "shipping_info": {
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "business_name": "Not applicable",
  "phone": {
    "country_code": "001",
    "national_number": "5039871234"
  },
  "address": {
    "line1": "1234 Broad St.",
    "city": "Portland",
    "state": "OR",
    "postal_code": "97216",
    "country_code": "US"
  }
  },
  "shipping_cost": {
  "amount": {
    "currency": "USD",
    "value": "15.01"
    }
  },
  "allow_tip": false
}'
```

This is the response:

```
"id":<Invoice ID>,
"number":"0004",
"template_id":"TEMP-66B140465N059453G",
"status":"DRAFT",
"merchant_info":{},
"shipping_info":{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","business_name":"Not applicable","phone":{"country_code":"001","national_number":"5039871234"},"address":{"line1":"1234 Broad St.","city":"Portland","state":"OR","postal_code":"97216","country_code":"US"}},
"items":[{"name":"Part E","quantity":2.0,"unit_price":{"currency":"USD","value":"10.15"}}],
"invoice_date":"2017-05-30 PDT",
"shipping_cost":{"amount":{"currency":"USD","value":"15.01"}},
"tax_calculated_after_discount":false,
"tax_inclusive":false,
"total_amount":{"currency":"USD","value":"35.31"},
"metadata":{"created_date":"2017-05-30 13:35:39 PDT"},
"allow_tip":false
```

If anybody has any ideas, would be happy to hear them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting in touch with someone at PayPal.  They said that the merchant_info has to be passed in the request in order for the template to work.
That basically defeated the purpose of using the templates for us, so I never bothered testing that.

In the end, I just decided to not use a template.

Comment: I tried pretty much every combination and never could get the template to work.  The only other thing I can see to do would be to use the template API to retrieve the template details and then fill in the invoice with that, but talk about a HUGE amount of work when just specifying a template to use would be so much easier.  There are also a lot of discrepancies in the docs, for phone numbers for example.  Sometimes they are string, others object, but they should always be object.

Comment: Good to know, @bvstone. Thanks for letting us know the results of your testing.

Answer (score 2):

We are correcting the instructions for how you use a Template ID.  Sorry for the confusion.

When you are doing a basic integration to create and send an invoice, you don't need to use Template at all.

Template is useful if you are creating a full invoicing app where you want the end user (invoicer) to be able to create templates and access them when creating invoices. See the PayPal.com website for how templates are used.

Regards,
Kristen

Comment: I was having issues with this too.  So are you saying that when using the invoicing API, the template_id does nothing and shouldn't be used?  Seems like it would be nice if we could use that in place of merchant_info, et al.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just looking to add your logo to your API created invoice, put this line at the end of your JSON before POSTing your draft:

```
},
   "note": "Thank you for your business!",
  "terms": "no refunds after 30 days",
  "logo_url": "https://link_to_your_log.PNG"
}
```